# Pause youtube video using javascript or jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe, youtube

I need to pause the youtube video using jQuery or javascript

my code in js

```
var class_name = $('#videobuttonChange').attr('class').split(' ')[1];
if (class_name == "play") {
    $("#vid_url").html('<iframe width="100%" height="270px" id="v_frame" src="http://www.youtube.com/v/uPiVOofEPHM?version=3&f=playlists&c=youtube_it&app=youtube_gdata&autoplay=1" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen wmode="Opaque"></iframe>');
} else {
    $("#vid_url").html('<iframe width="100%" height="270px" id="v_frame" src="http://www.youtube.com/v/uPiVOofEPHM?version=3&f=playlists&c=youtube_it&app=youtube_gdata" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen wmode="Opaque"></iframe>');
}
```

In else condition i need to pause the video but my code act as stopped the video. How to pause the video.

Anyone guide me.

Comment: One note: You would probably be better off using jQuery's $.hasClass() method to test for the presence of a class, instead of writing your code with the expectation that 'play' will always be the second class listed in the element's .className property. This code isn't as flexible to change later on.

Answer (score 2):

You could try conditionally configuring the `iframe` before appending it to the DOM:

```
var video = $('<iframe></iframe>');
    video.attr({'width': '100%',
                'height': '270px',
                'id': 'v_frame',
                'src': 'http://www.youtube.com/v/uPiVOofEPHM?version=3&f=playlists&c=youtube_it&app=youtube_gdata',
                'frameborder': '0',
                'allowfullscreen': '',
                'wmode': 'Opaque'});

if($('#videobuttonChange').hasClass('play')) {
   video.attr('src', video.attr('src') + '&autoplay=1');
}
video.appendTo($("#vid_url"));
```

Comment: Without using split for getting class name is ok but i need to pause the video. Is your code to pause the video?

Answer (score 0):

You can use **[YouTube JavaScript Player API](https://developers.google.com/youtube/js_api_reference)**

```
<body>
<div id="videobuttonChange" class="play"></div>
<div id="vid_url"></div>

<script src="http://www.youtube.com/iframe_api"></script>

<script>
    var player;

function onYouTubePlayerAPIReady() {   //create iframe in #vid_url   
    player = new YT.Player('vid_url', {
        height: '270px',
        width: '100%',
        videoId: 'uPiVOofEPHM'
    });

    setTimeout(function () { //as it is asynchronous  
        if ($('#videobuttonChange').hasClass("play")) {
            player.playVideo();
        } else {
            player.pauseVideo();
        }
    }, 2000);

}
</script>
```

Fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/code_snips/gNF6q/

Answer (score -2):

```
$('iframe').each(function(i,e){
    let iframeSrc = $(e).attr('src');
    $(e).attr('src',iframeSrc);
});
```

This will reset src for all videos, you can modify it to target only one