# stop youtube-iframe-video via js

Tags: javascript, api, iframe, youtube

How to stop the (youtube) video on click? I've tried so much, but I can't get it working … what am I doing wrong? Regarding to the docs and hundreds of posts in the internet this should work like a charm … but it does not:

html:

```
<iframe width="420" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/2BagaJFimzk?autohide=1&showinfo=0&rel=0&enablejsapi=1&origin=http%3A%2F%2Fjsfiddle.net" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
<button>please stop :(</button>
```

in js (with jquery and youtube-api loaded):

```
var thisvid;

function onYouTubePlayerAPIReady() {
    thisvid = new YT.Player($('iframe')[0]);
}

if (!thisvid) onYouTubePlayerAPIReady();

$('button').click(function () {
    thisvid.pauseVideo();
});
```

on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kz4z0j21/)

I can't create the video-iframe with JS … so I need a solution for a given iframe.

THX in advance!

Comment: You must create the video object using JavaScript, not HTML, in order to control it using the YouTube JavaScript API. http://stackoverflow.com/a/19854775/901048

Comment: See the console for errors: `Uncaught TypeError: thisvid.pauseVideo is not a function`

Comment: @blazemonger regarding to this https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference#Loading_a_Video_Player it should work by creating it with HTML! and that is what i want to figure out!

Comment: @RayonDabre I saw the errors … but how shall this help me?

Comment: Have you included the library ?

Comment: @RayonDabre Yes I did. you can see it in jsfiddle. otherwise I would get a lot more errors …

Comment: Try this: http://jsfiddle.net/kz4z0j21/1/

Comment: @RayonDabre Thanks, but as mentioned in my Question: I'm not looking for this js-solution. Youtube API says it should work, but it doesn't. I want to get it work with iframe already existing :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Regarding to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19603618/how-do-i-get-the-reference-to-an-existing-youtube-player), I found out that I made the following points wrong:
1. If "&origin=" is passed in iframe src -> it won't work.
2. at js-fiddle it only works if FWs & EXTs are loaded in body and not on load.

Well, that's all I need :)
Here is a working [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kz4z0j21/2/).

and the code …
… HTML:

```
<iframe width="420" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/2BagaJFimzk?autohide=1&showinfo=0&rel=0&enablejsapi=1&origin=http%3A%2F%2Fjsfiddle.net" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
<button>please stop :(</button>
```

… and the JS (of course you have to embed `https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api`):

```
var thisvid;

function onYouTubePlayerAPIReady() {
    thisvid = new YT.Player($('iframe')[0]);
}

if (!thisvid) onYouTubePlayerAPIReady();

$('button').click(function () {
    thisvid.pauseVideo();
});
```